# Name of web layout made up of full-width sections

Tags: website-design, page-layout

Is there a name for the type of web site layout in which

- the body of the page is divided into horizontal sections;
- each section is 100% wide but has content of fixed width (that is typically centered);
- the background of each section is usually different?

Examples:

- http://www.ogurcak.com/
- http://www.spacex.com/about

I am not looking for templates, just for the name of this kind of layout.

Edit: There does not seem to be a name for it. I will call it "sandwich layout".

Comment: I've just called it "latest style"

Comment: Sandwich layout. Nice. I might use that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really apply one label to this style.

- It is **fluid** in the sense that it expands and contracts to use the whole viewport.
- It typically used for **vertical** designs because it helps to break up the scrolling depth.
- It is most commonly found on **one page** sites because it is well suited to a lot of content.
- And it has certainly been a **fashionable** approach to site design over the past 18 months. I suspect it will begin to die back before long, at least in those cases where it's not particularly appropriate.

[**One Page Love**](http://onepagelove.com/) is a good reference for use cases in this style.

Comment: It seems that you cannot apply one of the *existing* labels to this style. We just need a new name for it, though that is for another thread.

Answer (score 0):

A common term is 'Vertically Scrolling Websites'.

Here is an [example](http://www.designbombs.com/tag/vertical-scroll/) of the term in use.

'Parallax Scrolling' is also used when the background images and content move at different speeds when scrolling.

Comment: Interesting. If you are right then there is no specific name for this kind of layout.

Comment: Aren't *all* sites 'vertically scrolling'?

Answer (score 0):

You can find these type sites searching vertical scrolling or infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

They're often referred to as: "single page websites."

- http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/the-science-behind-a-single-page-website/
- http://www.awwwards.com/websites/single-page/
- http://searchengineland.com/single-page-websites-seo-182506

Comment: A single page site / one page site is not a graphic style but a site with no additional pages. The poster is asking about the style itself. But, to your point, one page sites make frequent use of this style.